# "Ich zieh … und wünsch mir …": what is the subject?

Tags: verb, conjugation

In the [lyrics to the song "Mutter"](http://herzeleid.com/en/lyrics/mutter#mutter) there is this verse:

> ***ich zieh** sie auf ein weißes Haar
>
>   werf in die Luft die nasse Kette
>
>   **und wünsch mir**, dass ich eine Mutter hätte*

What is the subject of *wünsch*?

*wünsch* should be the imperative form of *wünschen* so that line is an order to somebody to wish that he had a mother. However, judging from the rest of the lyrics, it should be the narrator the one that wishes, so I would have expected something along the lines of *und ich wünsche mir, dass…*. Is it a deliberate artistic licence?

Comment: Maybe it helps to know that there was a word ommited: "ich zieh[e] sie auf ein weißes Haar... und **ich** wünsch[e] mir, dass ich eine Mutter hätte". So "wünsch" is not imperative, but rather the realis mood (or "Indikativ"). The English translation that is given in the linked article is quite good IMO.

Comment: @0x6d64 You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "ich" is the subject of all three verbs in that stanza. As a simple sentence, it would be:

"Ich zieh(e), werf(e), und wünsch(e) mir."

The "wünsch mir" is from the reflexive verb "sich wünschen" ("to wish"). The other words in the sentences just further describe the actions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _ich wünschE mir_? Or can the _-e_ ending be dropped like it happens for _ich habe_ → _ich hab'_?

Comment: @gioele: It can be dropped, just as you say. You can do this in spoken German (not just in lyrics), just don't use it in written language.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect this

Comment: Omitting a trailing "e" (in fact of any omitted letter) should be indicated with an apostrophe in written language. Hence: "Ich wünsch' mir".

Comment: @bitmask: Duden disagrees with you: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/ich-schreibe-oder-ich-schreib

Comment: @JohnSmithers: That holds for informal or sloppy language. But it certainly does not apply to formal language. It's more like an omission (of the apostrophe) that is done on a regular basis so it is not considered wrong any more to do. In any case I do *not* fully recognise the Duden's authoritativeness since they basically incorporate everything into the "official" Dudendeutsch, regardless how horrifically wrong it is.